# react native ios create actionable notification

Tags: ios, react-native, push-notification

I have checked with many blogs and examples.But I am not getting proper documentation or steps to add actions in iOS push notification.

My application builds using latest versions,

- **react-native => 0.62.2**
- **react => 16.11.0**
- **PushNotificationIOS Plugin => 1.2.2** [(Find plugin more details here)](https://github.com/react-native-community/push-notification-ios)
- Also Tried with [wix/react native notificatin](https://github.com/wix/react-native-notifications)

So using this plugin I am able to get normal notification, but in some case I need user action so want create Notification with Accept and Decline button. like below image,

[image: Actionable notification]

Also I have tried with [react-native-ios-notification-actions](https://github.com/holmesal/react-native-ios-notification-actions) plugin. But this plugin is not working with my current PushNotificationIOS plugin.

**So my question is,**

1. How I can register action as there is option given in plugin documentation to handle actionable parameter but not sure how to register it before sending the notification?
2. Is there any other plugin using that anyone achieve this functionality?
3. Any iOS guy can suggest me steps or way where I can merge native **UNNotificationAction** class code into it's **didReceiveRemoteNotification** method.
4. wix/react-native-notifications gives me error **["Error setting up in iOS (lib/dist/index.js doesn't exist)."](https://github.com/wix/react-native-notifications/issues/557)** If Anyone resolve this error or find solution share me your suggestions?